# Struts 2+ guice + EJB 3.0 speeding up database

Tags: struts2, ejb, guice

I´m using struts 2 with Google guice framework to inject services and EJB. The problem is when execute an action with multiple database queries the application goes slower. On the other hand, I've tried to use normal java classes (without "@inject") to make the queries and I get a speedup of 600%. I 'd like to keep the EJB structure.

I use Jprofiler to detect the bottleneck and the problem is in BCELStubBase.invoke(). Invoke takes five times more than the query inside invoke.

Any solution?

Comment: can you use some kind of profiler to see which part is actual bottleneck?

Comment: I use Jprofiler to detect the bottleneck and I think that is related to the injection of objects and more precisely the iterceptors guice uses. But this is just my guess, because i can't get sure of this.